# LibTiff API for Python with BigTiff Support

Tags: python, tiff, libtiff

I'm developing a Python script to process BigTiff files (4-10GB in size). I'll need to use a LibTiff API with BigTiff support, but the latest Python LibTiff I can find is 3.8.2. Is there another way I can access later versions of LibTiff (4.0 -) through Python?

Comment: what's the problem that you cannot access libtiff 4 with python? did u use:https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libtiff/0.4.0

Comment: I did, but that's 0.4.0, not 4.0 right? It installed fine and worked great, until I encountered files >4GB in size. I'm looking for a version with BigTiff support so I can handle these monsters.

Comment: @NathanWoo How did you end up solving your problem. It has been a while since you posting this question and I think libtiff now supports BigTiff.